# Magnific Popup : select specific file types

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I would like to select only jpg file and use magnific popup.

```
$('.entry-content').each(function () {
    $(this).magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image'
    });
});
```

Because of using `$('.entry-content')`, downloadable files are not working... 
Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Todd Thank you for editing. I read the help but still not sure how to use it...

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see the file ending is `.png`.

```
$('.entry-content').each(function () {
  if($(this).attr("src").match(/\.jpg$/)) {
    $(this).magnificPopup({
      delegate: 'a',
      type: 'image'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I checked and tried the code but not working. I also use var validExtensions = {jpg: true, jpeg: true}; still not able to select jpg files...

Comment: @okabe Does it work to manually pass the jpg selector to `magnificPopup`?

Comment: I'm new to jQuery and I didn't do correctly... not working. I will put the code and will ask again.

Answer (score 0):

It works now. Here is the code I use.

```
$('a[href*=".jpg"], a[href*=".jpeg"]').each(function(){
    $(this).magnificPopup({
        type:'image'
    });  
});
```

Thank you @Oleander and @Brad Larson